# Node and PayPal: Retrieve User Info after Payment

Tags: node.js, paypal

I'm using this tutorial:
https://www.nodejsera.com/paypal-payment-integration-using-nodejs-part2.html

The way it implements PayPal is:

```
// start payment process 
app.get('/buy' , ( req , res ) => {
    // create payment object 
    var payment = {
            "intent": "authorize",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/err"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": 39.00,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "description": " a book on mean stack "
    }]
    }   

    // call the create Pay method 
    createPay( payment ) 
        .then( ( transaction ) => {
            var id = transaction.id; 
            var links = transaction.links;
            var counter = links.length; 
            while( counter -- ) {
                if ( links[counter].method == 'REDIRECT') {
                    // redirect to paypal where user approves the transaction 
                    return res.redirect( links[counter].href )
                }
            }
        })
        .catch( ( err ) => { 
            console.log( err ); 
            res.redirect('/err');
        });
}); 
// helper functions 
var createPay = ( payment ) => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve , reject ) => {
        paypal.payment.create( payment , function( err , payment ) {
         if ( err ) {
             reject(err); 
         }
        else {
            resolve(payment); 
        }
        }); 
    });
}
```

Then user is redirected accordingly:

```
app.get('/success' , (req ,res ) => {
    res.redirect('/success.html');
    console.log(req.query);
})

// error page
app.get('/err' , (req , res) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.redirect('/err.html');
})
```

I'm using Sandbox, and dummy payment is successful. I want to send an email to the buyer (in this case, myself) when payment is completed. How do I retrieve that information (if payment was ok, user email and name, etc.)?

And, any recommendations on libraries to use inside node.js to implement automatic mailing (is nodemailer an option, or is it deprecated?) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the paypal api. But i think there are two things to keep in mind.

- Create a webhook to receive notifications (important to handle status changes there)
- Catch the immediate result at the redirect endpoint

Please double check what your redirect endpoint already receives from paypal.

```
app.get('/success' , (req ,res ) => {
    console.log(req.query); // should include payer id
    res.redirect('/success.html');
})
```